# how to initialize just one of the objects

Tags: python

how can i just initialize or is even possible to just initialize just on of these objects?

```
startsimulation = {}
startsimulation['obj'] = StartSimulation(client_socket)
startsimulation['threadSimulation'] = Thread(target=startsimulation['obj'].start_simulation, daemon=True)

startreading = {}
startreading['obj'] = StartReading(client_socket)
startreading['threadReading'] = Thread(target=startreading['obj'].start_reading, daemon=True)
```

because then in my code with the two initializations i get things like this ps:it's not wrong but it's not efficient

```
startsimulation['obj'].client = client_socket
startsimulation['obj'].send_handler_connect()
startsimulation['obj'].is_connected = True
startreading['obj'].client = client_socket
startreading['obj'].send_handler_connect()
startreading['obj'].is_connected = True
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a class, like that:

```
class Wrapper():
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
        self.thread = Thread(target=obj.start_reading, daemon=True)

    def send_handler_connect(self):
        self.obj.send_handler_connect()

obj1 = Wrapper(StartSimulation(client_socket))
obj2 = Wrapper(StartReading(client_socket))
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you might expect something like

```
a = b = 5
```

But you can not apply such assignment chaining into your application, as both `startsimulation` and `startreading` clearly referring to different instances, so assigning threads to them must be done with separate `Thread` calls.

But later on, you can simplify it to:

```
startreading['obj'].is_connected = startsimulation['obj'].is_connected = True
```

Or, if your aim is not to be explicit but brevity, you might handle this with function.